# Неверный emplace_hint

Tags: c++, c++11

```
template<typename KType, typename PType = std::less<KType>, typename AllocType = std::allocator<KType>>
class MySet
{
public:
    typedef std::set<KType, PType, AllocType> set_type;
    typedef typename set_type::iterator       iterator;
    typedef typename set_type::const_iterator const_iterator;

    MySet(std::initializer_list<KType> _Ilist): s(_Ilist)
    {
    }

    template <class... Args>
    iterator emplace_hint(const_iterator hint, Args&&... args) {
        return s.emplace_hint(hint, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    const_iterator cbegin() const { 
        return s.cbegin(); 
    }

private:
    set_type s;
};

//main

MySet<int> x { 1, 2, 3 };
x.emplace_hint(x.cbegin(), 4); // OK
x.emplace_hint(x.cbegin(), 5, 6, 7); // выдаёт ошибку
```

> Error C2440   'initializing': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to
>   'int'

Comment: почему нет показов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё правильно, `emplace`(как и `emplace_hint`) создаёт объект контейнера из переданных аргументов. У Вас в контейнере `int`ы, вот он и пытается создать `int`, но он не может создать `int`, так как Вы передаете слишком много аргументов.